# Conforming to the X delegates of X UITextView properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have, for example, 2 or more properties of type `UITextView` in one `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textTextView:UITextView!
```

Does it mean that in `viewDidLoad()` of `ViewController`, I have to set `ViewController` to be a delegate of each `UITextView` property?

Following up the question above:
Does it also mean that when using `UITextViewDelegate` methods, I have to write down those methods (such as `textViewDidBeginEditing()`, etc.) for each property separately?

Comment: For the last question, if that methods interests you: `func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { if textView == titleTextView {}. else if textView == textTextView {} else {} }`. Also, note that that method is Optional, you don't have to implements it. And you can make your delegate from InterfaceBuilder if needed

Comment: @Larme, thank u! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the delegate for both textviews but when it comes to `textViewDidBeginEditing()`, the code you put there is for both the textviews. If you want it to be different then you can specify the textview you want it to work with:

```swift
if textView == sometextview{
//Do what you want 
} else {
//If the textView isn't sometextView, Do something else
}
```

If you were wondering, the same rule applies to UITableViews and UICollectionViews

Comment: I see..! Thank you! Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags as well. They help in various situations. Suppose you have to make any other object as a delegate for both the textview, you don’t need to access the ViewController’s outlet properties, instead you can use the tag you set to identify the view.

```swift
// assign any integer value
view.tag = 20 

// compare this way
view.tag == 20
```